# Date-format Behaving Peculiarly

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format, date-formatting

we have a legacy system where they would be generating the current date and then sets that as a header to an excel.

Below java code in the simplified piece of my logic

Sometimes for this program I get the header output in a peculiar form

As example scenario is my  code is supposed to produce an header of 14 characters like 20170529121599 but sometimes it is producing a header of 15 characters like 201705291215992

Expected : `20170529121599`
Output : `201705291215992`

Why am I getting that extra character in some rare cases ?
This happens very rarely only and when this happens this extra character is causing the downstream system to fail.

Fix : We can fix this by timing the extra charters but I really want to know the reason behind  this so that it would help to fix similar issues.

Can someone help me with this  ?

---

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;    
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;   
import java.util.Date;   
import java.util.Locale;  

public class TestDateGeneration {   
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    DateFormatSymbols symbols;   
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;    
    symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("en", "US"));    
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E", symbols);    
    java.util.Date todayDate = new java.util.Date();

    String header = "";   
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");  
    String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(todayDate);    
    header = formatedDate+"\t";   

    System.out.println("output header " +header);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your source code.

Comment: I tried to reproduce, I can’t. On my Java 9 I generated 10 million `Date` objects using the no-arg `new Date()` and formatted them using your formatter. They all came out with 2-digit seconds in the 00–59 range.

Comment: How can you expect 20170529121599?? May 29, 2017 at 12 hours 15 minutes **99 seconds**? As you know, there are only 60 seconds in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Besides being incredibly difficult to read, your code doesn't produce your output (hint: include "formatedDate" in your println() call). An actual failing test would probably result in a better answer.

So if I were to guess at why it's not doing what you want, I would guess that your format is actually "yyyyMMddHHmmSS". The capital S means milliseconds (which is consistent with what your reported output shows). Note that "99" is invalid for seconds in the minute, but "990" and "992" are both valid milliseconds.

Comment: Hi Jwm....the output i gave is actually a sample output/issues we got in production. ...what i mean here is my code is supposed to produce a "header "  of 14 characters but sometimes it is producing a header of  15 characters.... in my code the date format i have used  SMALL s not CAPITAL S ( i.e " yyyyMMddHHmmss")....

Comment: I copied your code verbatim (although I did reformat it with whitespace) and ran it at https://www.compilejava.net/ and it put out no timestamp. I can make no assumptions about your production code, but small 's' would not produce '99' or '992'. I did confirm that "SS" will print 3 digits of milliseconds